# Native iOS app: How do I retrieve the Twitter user ID with iOS 5?

Tags: ios, twitter, native, single-sign-on

I'm writing an app that will feature SSO via Twitter.

So far, using the built-in functionality in iOS 5, I've been able to come up with something like this using internet search results:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController class]) 
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweeter setInitialText:@"Greg can't figure out Twitter in iOS 5"];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];
}
```

How would I get the Twitter user's "User ID" (@gregkrsak, in my case), if I wanted to store it for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TWTweetComposeViewController` does not give you access to the user's Twitter user ID, just as the `MFMailComposeViewController` does not give you access to the user's email address.

Fortunately, you can retrieve the user's Twitter user IDs (there may be more than one), but it takes a little more work. You will need to create an `ACAccountStore` object, query it for all Twitter `ACAccount` objects, and then extract the `account.username` property for each. In the process, the user will see an alert asking if he wants to give the app access to his Twitter accounts.

It's not hard to do all this, and a great resource is the WWDC 2011 session video (and slides) on Twitter.